# error: The connection was not closed, The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, ms-access

i do not know where my error is.. i already put connection.close() everywhere. i am using an access database in microsoft visual studio 2013 C#.. it works well without a database but when i try to add a database to it that is where the problems start to occur.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * from Login where [Username]='" + txtUser.Text + "' and [Password]='" + txtPass.Text + "' ";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        { 
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            connection.Open();
            Form main = new AdminMain();
            main.Show();
            this.Hide();

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT into LogHisto ([Username],[LogDate],[LogTime]) values ('" + txtUser.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username/Password is incorrect");
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT into LogHisto (Username,LogDate,LogTime) values ('" + txtUser.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: "that is where the problems start to occur." - what problems? Also: use parameterised queries.

Comment: i tried it but it still didnt work. im just trying to make my form save the login name and date to a database but since im opening and closing a connection between it and the database whenever a login is successful or not my code is getting mixed up. if i dont try to save the login it works pretty well but when i attempt to save it to a table in my database that is where i am hitting a dead end.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (count == 1)
    {
        connection.Open(); // <-------------FIRST TIME
        Form main = new AdminMain();
        main.Show();
        this.Hide();

        try
        {
            connection.Open();// <-------------SECOND TIME
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT into LogHisto ([Username],[LogDate],[LogTime]) values ('" + txtUser.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

In this code block you are opening same connection twice, because of that you have this exception.Just remove one of the `connection.Open()`; You need to remove one of the `connection.Close();` too.

Also you should use parameters in your queries ! This will prevent from sql injection. I advice you to make different class for `DataAccess`. This will prevent errors like this.